Terraform obtain IP of azure postgres flexible server
I have a Postgres flexible server deployed using private networking:
resource "azurerm_subnet" "vnet_subnet_postgres" {
  name                 = "my-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = [var.subnet]

  service_endpoints = [
    "Microsoft.Storage"
  ]

  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "private_dns_zone_postgres" {
  name                = "${var.name}.private.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group.name
}


resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "private_dns_zone_postgres_vnet_link" {
  name                  = "${var.name}-vnet-link"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone_postgres.name
  virtual_network_id    = var.vnet.id
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group.name
}


resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "postgres" {
  name                   = var.name
  resource_group_name    = var.resource_group.name
  location               = var.resource_group.location
  version                = var.postgres_version
  delegated_subnet_id    = azurerm_subnet.vnet_subnet_postgres.id
  private_dns_zone_id    = azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone_postgres.id
  administrator_login    = var.postgres_admin_login
  administrator_password = var.postgres_admin_password
  sku_name               = var.postgres_dimensions.tier
  storage_mb             = var.postgres_dimensions.storage_mb

  dynamic "high_availability" {
    for_each = var.high_availability_enabled ? [true] : []
    content {
      mode = var.high_availability_mode
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes  = [zone, high_availability.0.standby_availability_zone]
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.private_dns_zone_postgres_vnet_link
  ]
}

In my private DNS zone, a A record is created pointing to the auto-assigned IP of the postgres server.
As I cannot resolve the DNS name from my local machine but the IP, I want to obtain the auto-assigned IP address via terraform, however I do not find a way to achieve this.
Anyone an idea how to accomplish?

I found a way to achieve this using a private endpoint, however, I still have no information on how to do this with vnet integration.

Are you still facing the issue. @Eddy

Yes, still no solution

Have you tried using null_resource. @Eddy


Obtaining the IP of azure postgres flexible server using private end point terraform.

The main issue seems to be with the delegation that used in subnet. If you use the delegation, then the same subnet can't be accessed by private end point.
I tried an updated configuration as per the requirement and able to provision the requirement.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "samvk-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "samvk-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  private_endpoint_network_policies = "Enabled"

  service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Sql"] 
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "example" {
  name                = "samvkpgserver"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version             = "13"
  administrator_login = "psqladminun"
  administrator_password = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
  zone = 2
  storage_mb = 32768

  sku_name = "B_Standard_B1ms"

  storage_tier = "P4"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_network.example,
    azurerm_subnet.example,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "privatelink.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "samvklink"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "samvk-private-endpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "samvk-privatesc"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.example.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["postgresqlServer"]
  }
}

output "private_endpoint_ip_address" {
  value = azurerm_private_endpoint.example.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address
}

Deployment:



refer:
https://github.com/guillermo-musumeci/terraform-azure-postgresql-flexible-private-endpoint by guillermo-musumeci
azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry

Your solution does not use vnet integration, do you mean it is simply impossible without using private endpoint?

Without using a private endpoint, it's not possible to securely connect to the PostgreSQL Flexible Server within the same subnet, as VNet integration alone wouldn't work @Eddy

What do you mean? What exactly is insecure then?

Without a private endpoint, the PostgreSQL Flexible Server would be exposed to the public internet, making it less secure than using a private endpoint that ensures the connection remains within your VNet. @Eddy

But this is not my original question, how can I obtain the ip address which is assigned to the postgres server using vnet integration via terraform?
